# Getting two lists into a list of lists in a orderly fashion

Tags: python, python-3.x

- What I have
- l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
- l2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
- What i want:
- l3 = [ [1,6], [2,7], [3,8], [4,9], [5,10] ]

Comment: Use list(zip(l1,l2))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both lists have the same length:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
output = [[l1[i], l2[i]] for i in range(0, len(l1))]
print(output)  # [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

Comment: Just use `zip`? Why `range`? Also this is a mega duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use zip:

```py
zipped = zip(l1, l2)
result = [ x for x in zipped ]

# Result:
# [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```